# Chrome and Edge MDNS/IPv6 operation

Tags: windows, google-chrome, ipv6, microsoft-edge, mdns

I have a Linux device which hosts a website in LAN. The device has IPv6 address only, no IPv4. It also runs avahi-daemon to advertise its name over MDNS.

I can ping and ssh into it using its name successfully from Windows 10 and 11.
But the website opens only in Mozilla Firefox, both Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge are unable to open `http://device.local:8080/` link.

As the website works in Mozilla Firefox, and ping and ssh by device name work as well, I assume the device is set up correctly.

How do I enable MDNS and/or IPv6 operation in Chrome/Edge browsers?

Comment: Does the device have a global IPv6 address, or only a private (ULA) address, or neither (link-local only)?

Comment: @u1686_grawity Only link-local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome [does not query](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=530482) for IPv6 addresses (AAAA records) if it knows that it doesn't have *global* IPv6 connectivity. As your device doesn't have a global address, that strongly implies the PC doesn't have one either (as it would normally be set up automatically via RA) and therefore Chrome works in IPv4-only mode.

In the future you'll be able to use [Group Policy](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/187202?hl=en) to set the "Enable IPv6 reachability check override" policy for Chrome (and most likely also for Edge). However, this feature was only added to Chrome [*literally yesterday*](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/4930931) so it will take a few months for it to get into a stable release.

---

That aside, I would also strongly suggest setting up *at least* a private ULA address prefix for your LAN, due to various problems that come from link-local addresses needing to be used together with a 'zone index'. (Windows auto-detects it by guessing, but on Linux there a few deep issues that either prevent the mDNS resolver from being able to return the address together with zone index correctly, or Chrome from [being able to use](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=70762#c43) such an address.)

Comment: The device should be able to work in a network it's plugged into, so I can't rely on its specific configuration.

Comment: I highly doubt it'll ever be plugged into a network that has neither IPv4 _nor_ IPv6...

Comment: I agree. But is it guaranteed a network would have a private ULA address prefix?

Comment: No, but realistically it will have either a _global_ IPv6 prefix, or IPv4, or both.